# automated crane implementation by algorithm

Tags: algorithm, loading, containers, labview

i would like to know a basic algorithm to find the shortest route for container loading and unloading. i did research on optimal route for container loading and unloading, all the answers are too complicated for me to understand. research paper such as Kim and Kim (1999) minimized the sum of the set up time and the travel time of cranes in a container storage block by modeling the process as a mixed integer program (MIP). Zhang et al. (2002) employed a mixed integer programming (MIP) model to find the times and routes of crane movements among blocks so that the total delayed workload in the yard are minimized.

i don't need a very complex algorithm. my project is an automated gantry crane for container loading/unloading using labVIEW NI. so i just need a simple and usable algorithm.

i did some research and realized there is a conventional operation mode for container loading/unloading. it is called "door frame" route. if you have heard of it or seem it before, please do help me and give a some advice.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with routing algorithms, but there's an implementation of A* [here](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/quot-a-star-algorithm-quot/m-p/660929#M304339). Maybe it will help.

Also, if you have access to the LV Robotics module, I understand it includes some routing algorithms.